# Требует return, а он находится в блоке if

Tags: java, android

```
class SenderThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void , String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try{
        // Создаем сокет
        Socket socket=new Socket("192.168.0.102",6666);
        if(socket.getKeepAlive() == true) {
            // Получаем потоки ввод/вывода
            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);
            String line;
            out.writeUTF("getRandomNumber");
            out.flush();
            line = in.readUTF();
            return line.toString();
        }

}catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.toString();
    }

  }// тут требует return
}
```

Мне нужно возвращать конкретно line или ex. Спасибо

Comment: У вас нет `return` на случай не прохождения условия `if(socket.getKeepAlive() == true)` - можете там кинуть ошибку/вернуть пустую строку/ещё что-то

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Прежде всего Вам нужно решить, что нужно делать с переменной, если не выполняется условие `socket.getKeepAlive() == true`.

Если **невыполнение** этого условия является ошибкой, то Вам следует выбросить некоторый `Exception`:

```
throw new Exception("Socket not alive!");
```

Или, если это не является ошибкой и Вам нужно вернуть просто какую-то дефолтную или пустую строку или *null* можете прописать в блоке `else` сделать `return`. Например:

```
} else {
    return null;
    //or return "";
    //or return "default String";
}
```

Также, как уже было сказано предыдущим участником - если Вам нужно вернуть какой-то default-значение, то Вы можете инициализировать переменную **ДО** блока `try`.

Comment: Помогло решить проблему, но вот только он выдавал то что сокет мёртв. В чём проблема? Или создать отдельный вопрос?

Comment: @Евгений создайте отдельный вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Инициализируйте свою переменную перед try

```
String line = null;
try {
     //line = ...
} catch {
}
return line
```